# How to reset File type variable in dart / flutter with NULL Safety?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have initialized a `File` type variable in my Flutter Dart class as:

```
late File _image;
```

then I have assigned picked image from gallery to this variable eg.

```
_image = File(pickedFile.path);
```

I have displayed this image by using `_image` variable on the screen which is ok. I have a button delete button, which is used to remove selected image then need to re-pick new image. So I will have to reset this `_image` variable on delete button click.

Is there anyone who can help and suggest me. How can I reset this `_image` variable in NULL SAFETY in dart / flutter. Thanks a lot.

Comment: _image = NULL does not work due to NULL SAFETY, any other suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any working solution?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `late File _image;` you can use `File? _image;` which would allow null for assignment. If you use some operation on `_image` make sure to use `?.` operator (_image?.something).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am not able to send this _image variable as parameter in another widget. Getting error like widgetName(photo: _image), you cannot send NULL type to photo widget parameter. Here photo is variable of widgetName widget. It is just like NULL type is not matched with File type. Kindly share your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: You need to declare Photo as a `File? photo` in `widgetName`. You need to similar changes like this in other places in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to declare `late File _image;` with `import 'dart:io'`